# printing printf statement after giving input values in output console

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, mingw

I'm trying to write a c application that takes user input. I wrote a simple program, but it did work right. I'm using eclipse c/c++ toolkit. When I save>build>run the console stays blank. If I put in some input, the program then runs. First it prints the printf then the input I entered. It workes ok while running sample program in online compilers. Anyone got any ideas about why?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post a link to an image of the source... please include the source code directly in the question, using `code` tags.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. It works fine. How online compilers can affect your eclipse?

Comment: @Andrew wrong dupe. Eclipse & mingw need to flush for some reason. New line does not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.